# Highchart stacked bar yAxis stacked label issue

Tags: highcharts, label, stacked-chart

Here is js fiddle [highchart stacked bar stacked label issue](https://jsfiddle.net/irfanbsse/1v4nu1du/)

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'bar'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Stacked bar chart'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Apples', 'Oranges', 'Pears', 'Grapes', 'Bananas']
    },
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        title: {
            text: 'Total fruit consumption'
        },
        stackLabels: {
          enabled: true,
          align: 'right',
          style: {
            color: '#838383',
            fontSize:"12px",
            fontWeight:"normal",
            width:'60px'
          }
        }
    },
    legend: {
        reversed: true
    },
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            stacking: 'normal'
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'John',
        data: [5555555555555, 3, 4, 7, 2]
    }, {
        name: 'Jane',
        data: [2, 2, 3, 2, 1]
    }, {
        name: 'Joe',
        data: [3, 4, 4, 2, 5]
    }]
});
```

Is there anyway to set max length of bar so that yAxis label doesn't hide? or how can i show full label?currently its hidding some part of label if its value is large.

Comment: Set stackLabels.style.whiteSpace to 'nowrap' and chart.style.overflow to visible - this setting allow to see the overflown label https://jsfiddle.net/35reh42o/. You can also set the max value to be higher than your max data value.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to set `align` like this :

```
    labels: {
        align:'right'
    }
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/core972/1v4nu1du/1/)